# Find several items in one search with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a Users Collection and a Rooms Collection, the rooms collection stores references to the user id of the users in the room.

```
users = [
   {_id:1, name: 'name 1', type: 1},
   {_id:2, name: 'name 2', type: 1},
   {_id:3, name: 'name 3', type: 1},
   {_id:4, name: 'name 4', type: 1} 
];

room = {
  name: 'example room', 
  connected_users: [
    {user_id: '2', admin: false},
    {user_id: '3', admin: true}
  ]
};
```

Is there a way to search in the Users collection for the details of the connected users like this or similar?

```
db.users.find({_id: [2,3]});
```

That returns

```
[{_id:2, name: 'name 2', type: 1}, {_id:3, name: 'name 3', type: 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_in) operator is for:

```js
db.users.find({_id: {$in: [2,3]}});
```

Comment: I'm gonna vote this one for the reference to the documentation :D.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Users.find({_id: {$in: [2,3]}}).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna Accept the other one because of the referece tough.